# Is there any css selector for the following scenario

Tags: html, css

I need to apply styles only for first *line* *class* in this structure, is there any solution:

```css
.headercontainer .line > *:first-child {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="header">step1</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="header">step2</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Anything I missed here, please suggest.

Comment: [The 30 CSS Selectors You Must Memorize.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Typical fallacy of the `:first-child` / `:first-of-type` selectors because it only looks for the elements position, but not the class.

Comment: Also, if you need to apply styles to the `.line` element itself, do no write `.line > something`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. However, you can use a little trick as a workaround: set the border for all such elements, then reset the border back to the default for all divs following the first one.

```css
.headercontainer .line {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.headercontainer .line ~ .line {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="header">step1</div>
  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="header">step2</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

---

On the other hand, what is the purpose of the `.line` elements? If their one and only purpose is to serve as a line, then the answer would be: don't. Throw them away and put a bottom border on the first `.header` instead. That would simplify both the HTML and the CSS.

```css
.headercontainer .header:first-child {
  border-bottom: 6px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="header">step1</div>

  <div class="header">step2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that your second snippet is the **real** answer

Comment: @vals Yes, but by the time I thought of that, my original answer had already been upvoted, so I didn't want to throw that away!

Answer (score 2):

Css does not have `first-of-class` selector to select the first class of the given DOM element. In your case when class orders are going to remain. Then you can apply

```
.headercontainer .header:first-child + .line {
   color:red;
}
```

```css
.headercontainer .header:first-child + .line {
   color: red;
}

/* or:
.headercontainer .header:first-of-type + .line {
   color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="header">step1</div>
  <div class="line">red</div>

  <div class="header">step2</div>
  <div class="line">black</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. However, if you don't might using a different HTML element for the 'line' element. you can use `:first-of-type`

```css
.headercontainer p:first-of-type { 
       border: 3px solid yellow;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="headercontainer">
        <div class="header">step1</div>
        <p class="line">here</p>
        <div class="header">step2</div>
        <p class="line">there</p>
    </div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qym0wgxv/7/)**

`first-of-type` has a good browser support. Unfortunately, CSS doesn't provide a `:first-of-class` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is with the `order` *property*, which comes with the use of ***Flexbox / Grid***:

```css
.headercontainer {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically */
}

.headercontainer .line:first-child {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

/* or:
.headercontainer .line:first-of-type {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}
*/

.order {
  order: -1; /* puts the flex-item back to its desired position or above other siblings, because the default value of the "order" property is "0" */
}
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="line">border</div> <!-- needs to be positioned above other siblings in the DOM -->
  <div class="header order">step1</div>
  <div class="header">step2</div>
  <div class="line">no border</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained specifically how to write the selector you're asking for, however this isn't really the best practice.

To make the CSS and HTML more maintainable, and the job easier for your CSS Selector Engine, you'd be better off adding a new class to the element you'd like to style differently.

This allows the CSS to be modified more easily, and makes the HTML more obvious.